# tesseract compile issue: leptonica_OUTPUT_NAME is not set

Tags: cmake, tesseract, leptonica

I am trying to compile the source code of Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract).

But when running cmake, I always get the following error:

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: leptonica_OUTPUT_NAME
>       linked by target "libtesseract" in directory /home/test/github/tesseract

I have already downloaded the source code of leptonica (http://www.leptonica.com/download.html) and installed it.

I am wondering which value should I set to leptonica_OUTPUT_NAME.

Comment: There is a workaround that:

replacing all leptonica_OUTPUT_NAME-NOTFOUND to leptonica

for file CMakeCache.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. It seems that

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(Leptonica REQUIRED lept>=${MINIMUM_LEPTONICA_VERSION})
```

in `CMakeLists.txt` has problems finding leptonica whereas cmake's `find_package` just works fine:

```
if(NOT EXISTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.cppan)
#    if (NOT Leptonica_DIR AND NOT MSVC)
#        find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
#        pkg_check_modules(Leptonica REQUIRED lept>=${MINIMUM_LEPTONICA_VERSION})
#    else()
        find_package(Leptonica ${MINIMUM_LEPTONICA_VERSION} REQUIRED CONFIG)
#    endif()
else()
```

For completeness (both compiled from sources):

- tesseract 4.00.00alpha
- leptonica-1.74.4

Comment: I'm having the same issue, how does it know where to look for package leptonica??? Where do I add the folder name, and which folder from the leptonica sources do I need to add?